# Virtual PC - Windows XP Mode - Capturing hostname from guest?

Tags: hostname, windows-xp, windows-virtual-pc

I'm in the process of creating an auto-deploy customised Windows XP mode using Windows Virtual PC, I'm trying to get the guest to be named based on the hosts name but I'm not sure how the guest can pull this information from within itself.

I can't find anything regarding this, does anyone have any tricks on how I can pull this information and then transfer it to a text string / document for further processing. Net Use returned \TSCLIENT rather than the host name.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution, rather than having the guest OS trying to find a way to talk to the host OS I can have the host OS open the VHDs for the guest and placing the required PC name somewhere on the computer, either in the sysprep script or otherwise.